# Back propagation and Structure of a Neural Network in scikit-neuralnetwork

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to learn Neural Networks using [scikit-neuralnetwork](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide_model.html) framework and I know basics about Neural Networks and now trying to implement it with scikit-learn. but I am confused on 2 points.

1- what is the structure of this NN given below? Somehow, in some examples felt to me, some people don't put input layer as a layer. Otherwise, I am thinking this as a 2 layer NN has input layer with 100 nodes and 1 node at the ouput layer.

```
from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Layer

nn = Classifier(
   layers=[
    Layer("Maxout", units=100, pieces=2),
    Layer("Softmax")],
learning_rate=0.001,
n_iter=25)

nn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

2- Does scikit-neuralnetwork do back propagation within the code that I put above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- In scikit-neuralnetwork framework, the input layer is not shown but it is creared in the background as a layer when we feed the system with training data.

```
nn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

for example, let's suppose we are using iris flower dataset. It has 3 classes so if that's the case framework understands that from the y_train and it creates 3 input layer with 3 classes.

```
y_train = [0,0,0,1,2,]
X_train = [[ 7.1  3.   5.9  2.1]
           [ 5.9  3.   4.2  1.5]
           [ 5.5  2.4  3.7  1. ]
           [ 6.1  2.8  4.7  1.2]
           [ 5.   2.3  3.3  1. ]]
```

Except for  the last layer, all of the other layers are hidden layer. I saw that when I manipulate the last layer, got this error

```
    nn = Classifier(
    layers=[
            Layer("Maxout", units=100, pieces=2),
            Layer("Softmax",units=1)],   -----> if units is 3 that's ok!
            learning_rate=0.001,
            n_iter=25)
    "Mismatch between dataset size and units in output layer."
    AssertionError: Mismatch between dataset size and units in output layer.
```

2- More detailed explanation; thanks to @robintibor at datascience.stackexchange. He explained both questions here [Explanation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16819/back-propagation-and-structure-of-a-neural-network-in-scikit-neuralnetwork)

and thank you  @user7534232 for your answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

1.
Assuming that each training example in `X_train` has M features, and there are C classes in `y_train`:
The input layer (not explicitly shown in the code) has M nodes. The hidden layer has 100 nodes. The output layer has C nodes (each one encoding the score for each class).

2.
`.fit()` is a method that does that - feeds forward the training examples and uses back propagation to train the NN.

Also: perhaps you have to add `units=C` for the final layer - I assume this is a classification problem. If you need one value only (a score, not a class label), then use `Regressor`.

Comment: I am trying to implement that on iris flower dataset. The output layer in this code is that right `Layer("Softmax")`?  if that is to my understanding I need to add units to the last layer would be enough?  `Layer("Softmax", units=3)`

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure about `units=3`... :( As far as the original example in sknn docs say, maybe not necessary. I haven't used sknn in a long time and cannot recall at the moment. Try without it first and print the property `classes_` to check if the network correctly identified all of the classes in the dataset.

Comment: Thank you for help! @user7534232

Comment: When you're done: you can write here what worked for you, so that other people with the same issue have it for reference.

Comment: I haven't implemented that yet but for sure I am going go post it whenever I am sure about the answer :) thank you again